# sales calculation as per the below method

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am have some sales calculation and define some basic predicted sales as per the formula given.

df1: cut_of_sales

```
cut-off_sales
    1
    2
    1
    3
```

df2: actual df for data:

```
Sales
NA
NA
NA
NA
1.2    
2.1
1.4
1.1
2.1
1.4
1.1
1.2
2.1
1.4
1.1
1.2
2.1
1.4
1.1
2.3
```

First 4 quarters are NA. Keep them as they are.
Start with 5th row by adding the first value for cutoff_sales

```
Explanation: 
1. cutoff_sales is given predefined by the company, 4 values for each quaters are given. 

2. Add the q1 quarter of the cutoff sales with 2010q1 = ansq1

3. Add the q2 quater of the cutoff sales with 2010q2 = ansq2

4. Do the same for q3 and q4. 

Now the answer of above addition will, will be input for next 2011 quaters. 

so ansq1 + 2012q1 = ans...
ansq2 + 2012q2 = ans ....
and so on for below quarter answer for 2012 quaters will be input for 2013 and so on for rest of the 10 years.
```

Please help me in doing this addition.

I was only able to do the first year addition.

please help me writting a function or a loop that would be iterative as there would be many years coming up.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For updated question**

With the updated question, the following is one way to achieve the task. Since this is quarter data and the first four rows are NA, you can add the values of `cut_off` in `mydf1` to `Sales` first. Then, you create a grouping variable. `1` indicates first quarter. You can sum up `Sales` with `cumsum()` as I suggested in my previous answer. It seems that you want to keep the NAs. So I converted `0` to `NA` in the end.

```
mydf2$Sales[5:8] <- mydf2$Sales[5:8] + mydf1$cut_off

group_by(mydf2, quarter = rep(1:4, times = n()/4)) %>%
mutate(Sales = cumsum(if_else(is.na(Sales), 0, Sales)),
       Sales = na_if(Sales, 0))

   Sales quarter
   <dbl>   <int>
 1 NA          1
 2 NA          2
 3 NA          3
 4 NA          4
 5  2.20       1
 6  4.10       2
 7  2.40       3
 8  4.10       4
 9  4.30       1
10  5.50       2
11  3.50       3
12  5.30       4
13  6.40       1
14  6.90       2
15  4.60       3
16  6.50       4
17  8.50       1
18  8.30       2
19  5.70       3
20  8.80       4
```

**DATA**

```
mydf2 <- structure(list(Sales = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.2, 4.1, 2.4, 4.1, 
2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 2.3)), .Names = "Sales", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**For original question**

Here is one approach. I considered cases where you would have NA in your data. First, I added the values of `cut_off` in `mydf1`. Then, I create a new variable called `quarter` and defined groups. For each group, I applied `cumsum()` and summed up the values. If you do not have any NA, the final line would be `mutate(sales = cumsum(sales))` in the code below.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf2 %>%
mutate(sales = if_else(substr(sales_quarter, 1,4) == "2010", sales + mydf1$cut_off, sales)) %>%
group_by(quarter = substr(sales_quarter, 5, 6)) %>%
mutate(sales = cumsum(if_else(is.na(sales), 0, sales)))

   sales_quarter sales quarter
   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  
 1 2010Q1         2.20 Q1     
 2 2010Q2         4.10 Q2     
 3 2010Q3         2.40 Q3     
 4 2010Q4         4.10 Q4     
 5 2011Q1         4.30 Q1     
 6 2011Q2         5.50 Q2     
 7 2011Q3         3.50 Q3     
 8 2011Q4         5.30 Q4     
 9 2012Q1         6.40 Q1     
10 2012Q2         6.90 Q2     
11 2012Q3         4.60 Q3     
12 2012Q4         6.50 Q4     
13 2013Q1         8.50 Q1     
14 2013Q2         8.30 Q2     
15 2013Q3         5.70 Q3     
16 2013Q4         8.80 Q4
```

**DATA**

```
mydf1 <- structure(list(cut_off = c(1, 2, 1, 3)), .Names = "cut_off", row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

mydf2 <- structure(list(sales_quarter = c("2010Q1", "2010Q2", "2010Q3", 
"2010Q4", "2011Q1", "2011Q2", "2011Q3", "2011Q4", "2012Q1", "2012Q2", 
"2012Q3", "2012Q4", "2013Q1", "2013Q2", "2013Q3", "2013Q4"), 
sales = c(1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 
1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 1.4, 1.1, 2.3)), .Names = c("sales_quarter", 
"sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: what if i only have sales column and the cutoff_sales ..... can you please help me with this condition.

Comment: @bradonMc Could you edit your question? It is better to clarify your real situation.

Comment: @bradonMc I added a new code for the updated question.

Comment: is there substitute statement for na_if, cause i am using enterprise R which does not suport na_if.

Comment: @bradonMc Why don't you use `replace()` or `ifelse()`?

Answer (score 1):

New sequential answer:

```
> df
   year_quater sales pred_sales
1       2010Q1   1.2         NA
2       2010Q2   2.1         NA
3       2010Q3   1.4         NA
4       2010Q4   1.1         NA
5       2011Q1   2.1         NA
6       2011Q2   1.4         NA
7       2011Q3   1.1         NA
8       2011Q4   1.2         NA
9       2012Q1   2.1         NA
10      2012Q2   1.4         NA
11      2012Q3   1.1         NA
12      2012Q4   1.2         NA
13      2013Q1   2.1         NA
14      2013Q2   1.4         NA
15      2013Q3   1.1         NA
16      2013Q4   2.3         NA

pred <- c(1,2,1,3)

for(i in seq(1, nrow(df), 4)){
  df$pred_sales[i:(i+3)] <- df$sales[i:(i+3)] + pred
  pred <- df$pred_sales[i:(i+3)]
}

> df
   year_quater sales pred_sales
1       2010Q1   1.2        2.2
2       2010Q2   2.1        4.1
3       2010Q3   1.4        2.4
4       2010Q4   1.1        4.1
5       2011Q1   2.1        4.3
6       2011Q2   1.4        5.5
7       2011Q3   1.1        3.5
8       2011Q4   1.2        5.3
9       2012Q1   2.1        6.4
10      2012Q2   1.4        6.9
11      2012Q3   1.1        4.6
12      2012Q4   1.2        6.5
13      2013Q1   2.1        8.5
14      2013Q2   1.4        8.3
15      2013Q3   1.1        5.7
16      2013Q4   2.3        8.8
```

This answer creates a variable sequence by using the number of rows of your data and loops through every 4 rows, calculates the `pred_sales`, updates the `pred` values to use in the next loop iteration.

Comment: what if i dont have year and quater column in future just the sales and cutoff Df

Comment: You could also do it sequentially, I'll add a solution.

Comment: Thanks LAP for all your help.